# What is stored in a slice/array of funcs?

Tags: go, slice

I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere in the documentation

Given a slice like:

```
var funcs []func()
```

What is the underlying backing array?

At first I thought it would be an array of function pointers, but I have since seen that this is possible:

```
funcs = append(funcs, f.SomeFunc)
funcs[0]() // calls SomeFunc on the f
```

Where `f` is any type that has a method/receiver function defined for it.

So what *is* the underlying implementation?

Example program

```
package main

import "fmt"

func PrintStandalone() {
    fmt.Println("Standalone")
}

type Point struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (p *Point) PrintPoint() {
    fmt.Println("X: ", p.x, " Y: ", p.y)
}

type Coordinate struct {
    lat  int
    long int
}

func (c Coordinate) PrintCoordinate() {
    fmt.Println("Lat: ", c.lat, " Long: ", c.long)
}

func main() {

    p := Point{x: 1, y: 2}
    c := Coordinate{lat: 3, long: 4}

    var funcs []func()

    funcs = append(funcs, PrintStandalone)
    funcs = append(funcs, p.PrintPoint)
    funcs = append(funcs, c.PrintCoordinate)

    for _, fn := range funcs {
        fn()
    }

    p = Point{x: 5, y: 6}
    c = Coordinate{lat: 7, long: 8}

    for _, fn := range funcs {
        fn()
    }
}
```

When run, this program prints

```
Standalone
X:  1  Y:  2
Lat:  3  Long:  4
Standalone
X:  5  Y:  6
Lat:  3  Long:  4
```

Indicating that, depending on whether the receiver method is by pointer or by value, the function is called on the "same object" or on a copy of it.

Comment: The underlying type is a [function type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Function_types). The value is a function value. Using a method as a function value is called a [method value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values).

Answer (score 2):

> So what is the underlying type [of `[]func()`]?

It is `func()`.

The conceptual problem you seem to face is that methods are (more or less) plain functions in Go just having an additional receiver that is not part of the (call) signature). Details on this method values can be found here https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values.

Comment: I asked for the "underlying type" which, yes, of course it's `func()` - what I meant to ask was (I've edited the question) is "What is the underlying *implementation*? Let's say I wanted to create my own implementation of the Go spec - what should I make room for in an array of `func()` ?

Comment: @SRNissen The implementation is an unspecified implementation detail. Go source is open source and you can look it up. If you cannot find the implementation it might be helpful to ask on the golang-nuts mailing list. SO is not the right place for this type of question.

Comment: @SRNissen In the current implementation, it appears to be a pointer (every `func` type has a size of 8 bytes).

Comment: @SRNissen there would be no reason for it to be anything but a pointer, but what exactly that points to, and how it is executed is entirely implementation specific and outside of the language specification. If you wanted to created your own implementation, all you need to do is follow the spec and the rest is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Volker's answer, it might also help to imagine methods as functions that return closures over their receiver. I.e.

```
func (p *Point) PrintPoint() {
    fmt.Println("X: ", p.x, " Y: ", p.y)
}
```

is conceptually the same as

```
func PrintPoint(p *Point) func() {
    func() {
        fmt.Println("X: ", p.x, " Y: ", p.y)
    }
}
```

Now `p.PrintPoint` just becomes a simple function invocation `PrintPoint(&p)` which returns a `func()` -- the exact type your slice is supposed to hold. The closure semantics also explain why value and pointer receivers behave the way they do.